# MercadoLibre API gives error "getAuthUrl() should not be called statically"

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have the following 2 codes from library https://github.com/javiertelioz/mercadolibre to connect with MercadoLibre's API:

Class Meli.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Sources;

use App\Sources\MercadoLibre\Utils;

class Meli extends Utils {

    /**
     * @version 1.0.0
     */
    const VERSION  = "1.0.0";

    /**
     * Configuration for urls
     */
    protected $urls = array(
        'API_ROOT_URL' => 'https://api.mercadolibre.com',
        'AUTH_URL'     => 'http://auth.mercadolibre.com.ar/authorization',
        'OAUTH_URL'    => '/oauth/token'
    );

    /**
     * Configuration for CURL
     */
    protected $curl_opts = array(
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "MELI-PHP-SDK-1.0.0",
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60
    );

    protected $client_id;
    protected $client_secret;

    /**
     * Constructor method. Set all variables to connect in Meli
     *
     * @param string $client_id
     * @param string $client_secret
     * @param string $access_token
     */
    public function __construct($client_id, $client_secret, $urls = null, $curl_opts = null) {
        $this->client_id     = $client_id;
        $this->client_secret = $client_secret;
        $this->urls          = $urls ? $urls : $this->urls;
        $this->curl_opts     = $curl_opts ? $curl_opts : $this->curl_opts;
    }

    /**
     * Return an string with a complete Meli login url.
     *
     * @param string $redirect_uri
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthUrl($redirect_uri) {
        $params = array("client_id" => $this->client_id, "response_type" => "code", "redirect_uri" => $redirect_uri);
        $auth_uri = $this->urls['AUTH_URL'] . "?" . http_build_query($params);
        return $auth_uri;
    }
}
```

and the Controller MeliController.php with the following code:

```
class MeliController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Login Page (Mercado Libre)
     */
    public function login() {
        session()->regenerate();
        return view('auth/melilogin')->with('auth', [
            'url' => meli::getAuthUrl(env('ML_AUTHENTICATION_URL', '')),
        ]);
    }

    public function logout() {
        if(session('profile')) {
            session()->forget('profile');
            session()->flush();
        }
        return \Redirect::to('/auth/melilogin');
    }
}
```

But Im receiving error:

> Non-static method App\Sources\Meli::getAuthUrl() should not be called
>   statically

Three procedures I made with no success:

1- using facade (meli) as in the first example

> meli::getAuthUrl

2- replacing code:

```
public function getAuthUrl($redirect_uri) {
            $params = array("client_id" => $this->client_id, "response_type" => "code", "redirect_uri" => $redirect_uri);
            $auth_uri = $this->urls['AUTH_URL'] . "?" . http_build_query($params);
            return $auth_uri;
        }
    }
```

with public static function and $self instead of $this but with no success.

3- Making the call dynamic using:

```
    'url' => (new \App\Sources\Meli)->getAuthUrl(env('ML_AUTHENTICATION_URL', '')),
```

But receiving error

> Too few arguments to function App\Sources\Meli::__construct(), 0
>   passed in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/price2b/app/Http/Controllers/MeliController.php

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you the problem: you are calling the method statically (`meli::getAuthUrl(...)`), but it's not a static method. You have to call it on an instance of the class. This means that your third approach:

```
'url' => (new \App\Sources\Meli)->getAuthUrl(env('ML_AUTHENTICATION_URL', '')),
```

is the right one.

But, as you pointed out, you get a "too few arguments" error. This is because you are passing no arguments when you instantiate the `Meli` class. That is, `new \App\Sources\Meli` is equivalent to `new \App\Sources\Meli()`, passing zero arguments to the constructor.

But the constructor for the `Meli` class, which you posted above, looks like this:

```
public function __construct($client_id, $client_secret, $urls = null, $curl_opts = null)
```

So, you need to pass at least 2 arguments, not zero. In other words, at a minimum, something like this:

```
'url' => (new \App\Sources\Meli($someClientId, $someClientSecret))->getAuthUrl(env('ML_AUTHENTICATION_URL', '')),
```